# How to use ApiModelProperty in java using Swagger

Tags: java, swagger

I just want to make authorization required but I don't know exactly where to put: `@ApiModelProperty(value = "authorization", dataType = "java.lang.String", required = true) String authorization` in my method:

```
public Response getClienteFornitore(@HeaderParam("Authorization")  String authorization, @HeaderParam("StaySignedIn")  boolean staySignedIn, @PathParam("clienteFornitoreId") int clienteFornitoreId) {

....

}
```

I would really appreciate anyone who could help! Thank you!

Comment: You want it to be marked as required for the swagger docu, or you want to enforce that `authorization` is really set by the calling code?

Comment: I want to mark it as required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `authorization` required by adding an `@ApiParam` annotation to the respective parameter in your method signature:

```
public Response getClienteFornitore(
    @ApiParam(value = "Authorization token", required = true) @HeaderParam("Authorization")  String authorization,
    @HeaderParam("StaySignedIn")  boolean staySignedIn, 
    @PathParam("clienteFornitoreId") int clienteFornitoreId) {
    ...
}
```